# Observables - Angular - .map is not working but .subscribe does

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have an endpoint which is called and looks like this:

```
organizationSubsidiaries(sfid: string) {
  const url = `${this.baseURL}/${ENDPOINTS.organizations}/${this.organization.id}/${ENDPOINTS.subsidiaries}`;
  return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

If I call it like this it works and consoles correctly:

```
getOrgSubsidiaries(id) {
  return this.organizationSubsidiaries(id)
    .subscribe(data => { //changing this to .map means it won't work!

      let subsidiaryNames = []
      data.forEach(sub => {
        console.log(sub.SubsidiaryName)
        subsidiaryNames.push(sub.SubsidiaryName)
      })
      subsidiaryNames = subsidiaryNames.filter(this.onlyUnique);

      console.log('data from subsidiaries' + JSON.stringify(subsidiaryNames))

    });
}
```

When it's `.map` it doesn't work, but I need it to be `.map` as I need to `subscribe` to it in another file so I can asynchronously use the data in another component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.engagementService.getOrgSubsidiaries(id).subscribe(data => {
     this.orgSubsidiaries = data;
});
```

I need it so the `.map` also works as the `subscribe` does so I can actually `subscribe` to it and use the data in my other component!

In a slightly different issue this function in my other component doesn't recognise id.

Comment: I suspect the res.json() inside map() is breaking due to the content-type of the response. First, make sure the response is JSON format (I see .json() is called in your snippet). last, include .catch statement and lookup the thrown error to know why isn't working. You might see one of these messages if you console log the catch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse

Comment: in angular 6 you dont need `res.json()` in map as the response is json by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue depends on two things:

1. Which version of Angular you're using.
2. Whether you're using `HttpClient` or `Http`

---

**Let's talk about the Angular Version first:**

If you're using Angular 6, it comes with Rxjs 6. So on any `Observable` type value, you won't get to use operators like `map` directly by importing them from their paths and chaining them to the `Observable` value. In this case, you'll have to use `.pipe` that would be available on the `Observable` value and inside this `.pipe` you can then use your Operators.

An eg:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
return this.http.get('...').pipe(map(...))  // This returns an Observable too
```

If you're using Angular 5, 4, or 2, it comes with previous versions of Rxjs. So on any `Observable` type value, you will get to use operators like `map` directly by importing them from their paths and chaining them to the `Observable` value. In this case, you'll not have to use `.pipe`

An eg:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operators/map';
...
return this.http.get('...').map(...)  // This returns an Observable too
```

---

**Now, let's talk about whether you're using `HttpClient` or `Http`:**

If you're using `HttpClient`, then you won't have to map the response by calling `.json` on it. So you can simply do:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, ...) {}
...
return this.http.get(...); // This will return the Actual Response DATA
```

If you're using `Http`, then you'll have to `map` the response by calling `.json` on it.

So in case of Angular 2,4,5, it would look something like:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operators/map'
...
constructor(private http: Http, ...) {}
...
return this.http.get(...).map(res => res.json());
```

And in case of Angular 6, I guess Http has been removed. So you won't be able to inject it as a dependency in the first place.

### UPDATE

I think the issue is that you haven't injected `Http` or `HttpClient` as a Dependency in your `EngagementService` service. And hence the error.

In case of Angular 6:

Just add a `constructor` as well, that injects `HttpClient` as a dependency.

Comment: I'm angular 6, i tried the first method, there aren't errors but im still not able to console out the data as I was with the subscribe method, Im not sure about http or client I don't see either in the file

Comment: except for this: import { URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Comment: Perhaps the way i've written my function - it won't work with how map works?

Comment: Can you please create a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue of yours?

Comment: Let me know if thats okay please, sorry its not amazing my projects not simple

Comment: I'd need the code from the `EngagementService` as well to work with it. Things like what exactly is `http` Is it of type `Http` or `HttpClient` need to understand that.

Comment: Hello.component is meant to be the engagementservice

Comment: How can a Component be a service? I want to see the code of your `EngagementService` file is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

use the pipe in rxjs 6

```
 return this.http.get(url).pipe( map(res => res.json()));
```

import the map

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

Comment: `res.json()` is not required in Angular 6 if you are using HttpClient

Comment: I get this error when i hover over the map part in your answer ' Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'? '

Comment: what's the rxjs version u ar using

Comment: I'm using Version 6.1.0

Comment: npm says 6.1.0 but my package json says 5.5.0

Comment: The error disappeared but the console of the data still did not work,

Comment: in angular 6 you dont to need to convert to `.json()`. Angular gonna do that for us. just remove the whole map operator if you're on using it for `.json()` only

Comment: How would I write the line without the .map?

Comment: just `return this.http.get(url)`